# WooCommerce - Turning the product tag cloud into a complex refine feature

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

**QUESTION: How am I able to combine these two blocks of code so they work as one?**

I do not require any shortcode solutions, I prefer the function format used in the first block of code, however the second block has some essential functionality.

The first block of code I have managed to construct allows for the WooCommerce product tag cloud to benefit from the following advanced features:

- Alphabetised list.
- Display product quantity totals.
- Dynamic sizing and scrollable overflow box used if list becomes too long.
- If a product archive level becomes empty (i.e. no 'in stock' products to show) then the whole tag level becomes hidden.
- Hidden product tag levels then automatically 302 redirect themselves to the top level 'shop' page.

The code to achieve this is as follows:

```
/* TURN PRODUCT TAG CLOUD INTO ALPHABETICAL LIST WITH TAG TOTALS COUNT VISIBLE */

function woocommerce_product_tag_cloud_widget_filter($args) {
    $args = array(
        'smallest' => 14, 
        'largest' => 14, 
        'format' => 'list', 
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 
        'unit' => 'px',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'number' => 0,
    );

    echo "<div style='padding-left: 20px; min-height: 50px; max-height: 400px; overflow: auto;'>";
    return $args;
    echo "</div>";
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_tag_cloud_widget_args', 'woocommerce_product_tag_cloud_widget_filter');

/* HIDE PRODUCT TAG ARCHIVE PAGES WHEN THEY HAVE NO 'IN STOCK' PRODUCTS */

function hide_empty_tags( $terms, $taxonomies) {
    $new_terms = array();
    
    if ( in_array( 'product_tag', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
            if ($term->count >0){
                $new_terms[] = $term;
            }
        }
        $terms = $new_terms;
    }
    return $terms;
}

add_filter( 'get_terms', 'hide_empty_tags', 10, 3 );

/* REDIRECTS TO SHOP IF THERE ARE NO 'IN STOCK' PRODUCTS IN THE PRODUCT TAG ARCHIVE PAGE */

function redirect_to_shop(){
    global $wp_query;

    if( is_woocommerce() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ){
        the_post();
    $post_url = "/shop";
    wp_safe_redirect($post_url , 302 );
    exit;
    }
} 

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_shop');
```

The second block of code allows the product tag cloud to work dynamically in the same way you would expect a refine block to work - only showing relevant product tags at each product category level.

The shortcode is as follows:

```
[custom_product_tags]
```

The code is as follows:

```
add_shortcode('custom_product_tags', 'custom_product_tag_cloud_func');
function custom_product_tag_cloud_func() {
    if (is_shop()) {
        //return all tags
        $content = '<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><div class="tagcloud">';
        $tags = wp_tag_cloud(array(
            'format'                    => 'array',
            'taxonomy'                  => 'product_tag',
            'link'                      => 'view'
        ));
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $content .= $tag;
        }
        $content .= '</div></div>';
        return $content;
    }
    global $wp;
    $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
    if(strpos($current_slug, '/') !== false) {
        // explodable
        $newtest = explode('/', $current_slug);
        $current_slug = array_pop($newtest);
    } 
    $args = array(
        'category' => array( $current_slug ),
        'limit' => -1
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    $tags_objects = array();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $tags = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $slug = $tag->slug;
            $cat_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
            $tag->link = get_site_url()."/".$cat_slug."?product_tag=".$slug;
            array_push($tags_objects, $tag);
        }
    }
    $tags_objects = array_unique($tags_objects, SORT_REGULAR);
    $tag_cloud = wp_generate_tag_cloud($tags_objects);
    $content = '<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><div class="tagcloud">';
    $content .= $tag_cloud;
    $content .= '</div></div>';
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code Snippet:

```
/* CREATE A DYNAMIC PRODUCT TAG LIST - WITH SHORTCODE - WHICH ACTS DYNAMICALLY BASED ON WHERE YOU ARE WITHIN THE WEBSITE */

add_shortcode('dynamic_tag_cloud', 'custom_product_tag_cloud_func');

function custom_product_tag_cloud_func() {
   if (is_shop()) {
       $args= array(
           'smallest' => 14,
           'largest' => 14,
           'format' => 'list',
           'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
           'unit' => 'px',
           'show_count' => 1,
           'number' => 0,
       );

       echo'<div class="widget woocommerce widget_product_tag_cloud"><span class="gamma widget-title">Related tags</span><div class="tagcloud" style="min-height: 50px; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;"><ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';
       wp_tag_cloud($args);
       echo '</ul></div></div>';
   }

    global $wp;

    $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );

    if(strpos($current_slug, '/') !== false) {
        $newtest = explode('/', $current_slug);
        $current_slug = array_pop($newtest);
    } 

    $args = array(
        'category' => array( $current_slug ),
        'limit' => -1,
    );

    $products = wc_get_products( $args );

    $tags_objects = array();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $tags = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );
        
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $slug = $tag->slug;
            $cat_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
            $tag->link = get_term_link( $tag ); //get_site_url()."/".$cat_slug."?product_tag=".$slug;
            array_push($tags_objects,$tag);
        }
    }

    $tags_objects = array_unique($tags_objects, SORT_REGULAR);
    
    $args = array(
        'smallest' => 14,
        'largest' => 14,
        'format' => 'list',
        'unit' => 'px',
        'show_count' => 1,
        'number' => 0,
    );

    $tag_cloud = wp_generate_tag_cloud($tags_objects,$args);
    
    if(is_product_category()){
        echo'<div class="widget woocommerce widget_product_tag_cloud"><span class="gamma widget-title">Related tags</span><div class="tagcloud" style="min-height: 50px; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;"><ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';
        echo $tag_cloud;
        echo '</ul></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to also add - The correct answer can be combined with the initial block of code from the question (which doesn't need any changes to be made) to give some really cool functionality to the WooCommerce product tag cloud.